# How to make react do only 1 render after calling zustand's set two time?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I want to call more actions from one action using Zustand.

I created something similar to this:

```
  actionA() {
    set((state) =>
      produce(state, (draft) => {
        /* do changes */
      }),
    );
  },

  actionB() {
    set((state) =>
      produce(state, (draft) => {
        /* do changes */
      }),
    );
  },

  mainAction() {
    get().actionA();
    get().actionB();
  }
```

- Both `actionA` and `actionB` are doing a lot of changes to the state.
- `actionB` should work with the new state that was created by `actionA`

This is working fine, so I get the correct state at the end, but the problem is that after zustand's `set` react rerenders the components. I was expecting that only 1 render should happen similarly to when a setState called more times, so I was expecting some kind of 'batching'. Is not happening, I see the state (only for a very short time) that was created in `actionA`.

Is there any good practice how to do only 1 set in `mainAction` and keep the logic in `actionA` and `actionB`?

Comment: You can follow this guide. You may need to use unstable_batchedUpdates. [Zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/guides/event-handler-in-pre-react-18.md).

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique Thanks, I tried it. It seems working but the render triggered 2 times. It was only not applied to the dom, so I am still searching a differnt solution.

Comment: Have you verified the rerenders are not due to React 18's strict mode being enabled in development by default? See the notes here: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#enabling-strict-mode-for-entire-app

Comment: @nbokmans I did not mention, but I am using currently 17

Comment: Can you please create code sandbox with a small example?